# Verb meaning "to remove style" (as in CSS)

Tags: single-word-requests

Concerning CSS ([Cascading Style Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)): to *style* something means to apply CSS to it (not necessarily to literally render using CSS, but to apply some stylized visual design in a general sense).

Is there a verb that means the opposite – to remove/reduce stylized visual design, to make something more basic/plain in appearance?

*Unstyle* and/or *destyle* seem reasonable but I could not find either in various dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [strip (something) down](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strip-sth-down) at Cambridge dictionary, defined as

> to remove the unnecessary parts of a system or process in order to make it more simple or efficient.